# How do I use Docker --format when the key contains a period?

Tags: docker

I have a Docker network with a field that I want to query with `docker inspect --format '{{...}}'`:

```json
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        // ...
        "Options": {
            // ...
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0"
        }
    }
]
```

Because period is used as a delimiter in the `--format` expression, how can I reference the field above? I can't just say `{{.Options.com.docker.network.bridge.name}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `index`:

```
{{index .Options "com.docker.network.bridge.name"}}
```

This functionality comes from the upstream [text/template](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template) library.